# A Jenkins job was manually configured from the web UI. How can I translate all the configuration details to a configuration-as-code file?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

All of the below details are currently configured from the web UI in the job's "configure" page manually. I'm trying to have this configuration in a yaml file using Jenkins `configuration-as-code` and `job-dsl` plugin. How can I achieve this? I've dug through plugin's docs and examples but not much help as there are a lot of configuration details below that aren't included.

```
- display name
- description 
-  branch source
    - github 
        - credential 
        - repo https url 
    - behaviours
        - within repo: discover pul requests from origin 
            - strategy: the current pull request revision 
        - general 
             disable github notifications
             prune stale remote-tracking branches
        - property strategy
             all branches get the same properties
        - build strategy 
             skip initial build on first branch indexing 
- Build configuration 
    - mode: by Jenkinsfile 
        - script path: Jenkinsfile
- Scan repository triggers
    - periodically if not otherwise run 
        - interval: 30min 
- Orphaned item strategy 
    - discard old items
- Appearance
    - icon: Metadata Folder Icon
- Health metrics
     Child item with worst health 
        - recursive
```

I've dug through all the docs and examples for `configuration-as-code` & `job-dsl` as well as various online resources to no avail, as many of the configuration details are quite specific and aren't shown.